# JavaFX tableview resizeable and unresizeable column

Tags: java, javafx, resize, width, tableview

I have a TableView and in this TableView, there are 5 columns. One of the columns only contains the number of the row in the TableView, it simply counts them. The following behavior is what I want to achieve:

1. Number Column shall have a width fitting its content
2. Number Column shall not be resizeable
3. The other columns shall be resizeable
4. The other columns can and shall truncate their content when it is too long, so that they fit into the area of the TableView and no horizontal scrollbar is visible

I have 5 TableView column, which I created like this:

```
TableColumn numberColumn = new TableColumn("#");
numberColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Vocable, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Vocable, String> vocableCellDataFeature) {
        return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(getItems().indexOf(vocableCellDataFeature.getValue()) + "");
    }
});
numberColumn.setResizable(false);
//numberColumn.setMaxWidth(numberColumn.getMaxWidth()-20);

TableColumn<Vocable, String> firstLanguageColumn = new TableColumn<>(Settings.FIRST_LANGUAGE);
firstLanguageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstLanguageTranslationsAsString"));
firstLanguageColumn.setMinWidth(100);

TableColumn<Vocable, String> firstLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn = new TableColumn<>(Settings.FIRST_LANGUAGE_PHONETIC_SCRIPT);
firstLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstLanguagePhoneticScriptsAsString"));
firstLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn.setMinWidth(100);

TableColumn<Vocable, String> secondLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn = new TableColumn<>(Settings.SECOND_LANGUAGE_PHONETIC_SCRIPT);
secondLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("secondLanguagePhoneticScriptsAsString"));
secondLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn.setMinWidth(100);

TableColumn<Vocable, String> secondLanguageColumn = new TableColumn<>(Settings.SECOND_LANGUAGE);
secondLanguageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("secondLanguageTranslationsAsString"));
secondLanguageColumn.setMinWidth(100);

getColumns().add(numberColumn);
getColumns().add(firstLanguageColumn);
getColumns().add(firstLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn);
getColumns().add(secondLanguagePhoneticScriptColumn);
getColumns().add(secondLanguageColumn);

getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

So my question is: How can I achieve this kind of behavior in the JavaFX TableView? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Bind the column max and min widths to a fraction of the TableView width.  Make the fractions add up to 1

```
    ?Col.maxWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().multiply(.25));
    ?Col.minWidthProperty().bind(amountCol.maxWidthProperty());
```

You should really do something like this

```
    ?Col.minWidthProperty().bind(tableView.widthProperty().subtract(20).multiply(.25));
```

except that causes an error.  It says `A bound value cannot be set.` but that's not true as it only has a problem with subtraction resulting in <0.  `.subtract(-10)` works fine, except for not being what you want.

There must be a bug in the bindings somewhere.

edit: If you resize columns bigger than the table then you'll get a scroll bar.  So when one gets bigger, others have to get smaller.  I find this annoying when all columns change some percentage but maybe like this is acceptable.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<LineItem> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        items.addAll(new LineItem(1,"string1","string2",123.45),
                     new LineItem(1,"string1","string2",123.45),
                     new LineItem(1,"string1","string2",123.45));

        TableView<LineItem> tableView = new TableView<>(items);

        TableColumn<LineItem,String> numCol = new TableColumn<>("num");
        TableColumn<LineItem,String> descCol = new TableColumn<>("desc");
        TableColumn<LineItem,String> nameCol = new TableColumn<>("name");
        TableColumn<LineItem, Double> amountCol = new TableColumn<>("amount");

        numCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("num"));
        descCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("desc"));
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        amountCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amount"));

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(numCol,descCol,nameCol,amountCol);

        //col width logic, or lack thereof
        numCol.setPrefWidth(20);
        numCol.setResizable(false);
        tableView.setColumnResizePolicy((TableView.ResizeFeatures param) -> {
            if (param.getColumn() == null )return false;
            double delta = param.getDelta();
            ObservableList<TableColumn> cols = param.getTable().getColumns();
            int colIdx = cols.indexOf(param.getColumn());
            param.getColumn().setMinWidth(param.getColumn().getWidth() + delta);
            param.getColumn().setMaxWidth(param.getColumn().getWidth() + delta);
            if (colIdx < cols.size() -1){
                cols.get(colIdx+1).setMinWidth(cols.get(colIdx+1).getWidth() - delta);
                cols.get(colIdx+1).setMaxWidth(cols.get(colIdx+1).getWidth() - delta);
            } else {
                stage.setWidth(stage.getWidth() + delta);
            }
            return true;
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(tableView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public class LineItem {

        private final SimpleIntegerProperty num = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final SimpleStringProperty desc = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final SimpleDoubleProperty amount = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public SimpleIntegerProperty numProperty() {return num;}
        public SimpleStringProperty descProperty() {return desc;}
        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {return name;}
        public SimpleDoubleProperty amountProperty() {return amount;}

        public LineItem(int num, String desc, String name, double amount) {
            this.num.set(num); 
            this.desc.set(desc);
            this.name.set(name);
            this.amount.set(amount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know I could also bind these properties! This helps me at least with the other (resizable) widths.However, this solution results in a resizing table column when I resize the application window. I'd like to have it in a way, that it only takes as much space as needed because of the content and never resize. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you want something like [this.  ] (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY) .  But the columns won't be resizable.  Maybe you need some custom behavior, If so, I think it's another question.

Comment: That would make them all unresizeable. I was searching for something to make the numberColumn unresizeable but leave the other ones resizeable - I know, very special ;)

Comment: That's doable, the problem is having either the table resize or the other columns resize to fill the space so you don't get a scrollbar.  I suggest a listener on columnWidthProperty.  I use one program like that and I hate it, All the other columns resize when you don't expect it.

Comment: What do you mean by "when you don't expect them [to resize]"? If one column had the same width all the time and the other ones resize like they usually do, where is the unexpected thing happening?

To me it seems to be the other way around:
A number column automatically resizing so that the numbers are not completely visible seems odd, because you'd expect the application to know the necessary width, since it knows the number of rows. Additionally the number column is unlikely to become very wide, so why resize it?  - Do I misunderstand your comment?